# How to grid a workspace correclty into n x m cells

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have this **input image**, and I want to grid it into cells `22 x 10` to quantify blocks' color later.

[image: roi]

When I tried to reuse this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66863584) which has worked perfectly for the `4 x 4` workspace, I get the wrong grid:

[image: result]

> Note that this **dynamic approach is necessary**, as I might have a different number of cells, resolution, etc...

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my modification of the original solution? thanks in advance.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import cv2


def gridWorkspace(roi, gridSize=(10, 22), verbose=True):
    """
    Function: gridWorkspace, to find the contours of the red markers.
    ---
    Parameters:
    @param: roi, nd array, cropped region of interest.
    @param: gridSize, tuple, lenght/width or the Workspace.
    @param: verbose, boolean, to show the output of the function. 
    ---
    @return: cellList, list, cells coordinates list,
            cellCenters, list, cells centers list.
    """
    # Store a deep copy for results:
    roi_copy = roi.copy()

    # Divide the image into a grid:
    verticalCells   = gridSize[1]
    horizontalCells = gridSize[0]

    # Cell dimensions
    bigRectWidth  =  roi.shape[1] 
    bigRectHeight =  roi.shape[0]

    cellWidth = bigRectWidth // verticalCells
    cellHeight = bigRectHeight // horizontalCells

    # Store the cells here:
    cellList = []

    # Store cell centers here:
    cellCenters = []

    # Loop thru vertical dimension:
    for j in range(verticalCells):

        # Cell starting y position:
        yo = j * cellHeight

        # Loop thru horizontal dimension:
        for i in range(horizontalCells):

            # Cell starting x position:
            xo = i * cellWidth

            # Cell Dimensions:
            cX = int(xo)
            cY = int(yo)

            # Crop current cell:
            currentCell = roi[cY:cY + cellHeight, cX:cX + cellWidth]

            # into the cell list:
            cellList.append(currentCell)

            # Store cell center:
            cellCenters.append((cX + 0.5 * cellWidth, cY + 0.5 * cellHeight))

            # Draw Cell
            cv2.rectangle(roi_copy, (cX, cY), (cX + cellWidth, cY + cellHeight), (100, 100, 255), 1)

    # Visualize results
    if(verbose):
        cv2.namedWindow("Grid", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("Grid", roi_copy)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    return cellList, cellCenters

roi = cv2.imread("DsUYY.png")
res = gridWorkspace(roi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check verticalCells, horizontalCells and gridSize[index] twice!!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import cv2


def gridWorkspace(roi, gridSize=(22, 10), verbose=True):
    """
    Function: gridWorkspace, to find the contours of the red markers.
    ---
    Parameters:
    @param: roi, nd array, cropped region of interest.
    @param: gridSize, tuple, lenght/width or the Workspace.
    @param: verbose, boolean, to show the output of the function. 
    ---
    @return: cellList, list, cells coordinates list,
            cellCenters, list, cells centers list.
    """
    # Store a deep copy for results:
    roi_copy = roi.copy()

    # Divide the image into a grid:
    verticalCells   = gridSize[1]
    horizontalCells = gridSize[0]

    # Cell dimensions
    bigRectWidth  =  roi.shape[1] 
    bigRectHeight =  roi.shape[0]

    cellWidth = bigRectWidth // horizontalCells
    cellHeight = bigRectHeight // verticalCells

    # Store the cells here:
    cellList = []

    # Store cell centers here:
    cellCenters = []

    # Loop thru vertical dimension:
    for j in range(verticalCells):

        # Cell starting y position:
        yo = j * cellHeight

        # Loop thru horizontal dimension:
        for i in range(horizontalCells):

            # Cell starting x position:
            xo = i * cellWidth

            # Cell Dimensions:
            cX = int(xo)
            cY = int(yo)

            # Crop current cell:
            currentCell = roi[cY:cY + cellHeight, cX:cX + cellWidth]

            # into the cell list:
            cellList.append(currentCell)

            # Store cell center:
            cellCenters.append((cX + 0.5 * cellWidth, cY + 0.5 * cellHeight))

            # Draw Cell
            cv2.rectangle(roi_copy, (cX, cY), (cX + cellWidth, cY + cellHeight), (100, 100, 255), 1)

    # Visualize results
    if(verbose):
        cv2.namedWindow("Grid", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("Grid", roi_copy)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    return cellList, cellCenters

roi = cv2.imread("/Users/buenos/buenos/playground/python/assets/DsUYY.png")
res = gridWorkspace(roi)
```

[image]